# How bad are duplicate entries in sources.list?

Tags: apt, updates, software-sources, source

What is sources.list?  Is it like 'registry?'

How important is it it to keep it 'clean?'

When I did

```
sudo apt-get update
```

the last lines to display were these:

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ raring/partner amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_raring_partner_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ raring/partner i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_raring_partner_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

Do I need to eliminate these?

If so, do I just find that file, back it up, and use gedit to edit?

Edit for Erik:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list:## 'partner' repository.
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner
/etc/apt/sources.list:## 'partner' repository.
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:## 'partner' repository.
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:## 'partner' repository.
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner
```

Thanks Eric!

Comment: Basicly, you have to search for duplicate lines in "/etc/apt/sources.list" and any ".list" file inside "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/". Please, include in your question the output of `grep -iR partner /etc/apt/sources.list*`